# How to convert epoch time stamp to PST date in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table column with epoch time stamp I want to covert that column into date in PST timing.

example `select epoch_time from table;`

```
input
    epoch_time
    1262304151988
    1262304157756
```

output

```
epoch_time
    YYY-MM_DD
    YYY-MM_DD
```

In PST

Comment: Give a full example including desired results - actual data as you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_utc_timestamp(1262304151988,'PST');
```

> 2010-01-01 00:02:31

```
select to_utc_timestamp(1262304157756,'PST');
```

> 2010-01-01 00:02:37

Comment: Add `to_date()` to convert timestamps to dates as in desired output